# If errors occur while accessing a file or the data is invalid, how do I get the program to terminate?

Tags: java

I've figured out how to get the program to terminate if the file name doesn't exist but I'm not sure how to do the same if the file itself includes anything besides integers.

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Enter the name for a file: ");
    filename = keyboard.nextLine();
} else {
    filename = args[0];
}

File file = new File(filename);

if (file.exists() != true) {
    System.out.println("File name does not exist");
    System.exit(1);
}

Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Right now, if I were to put a character other than an integer into an existing file I get an error. Instead, I want the program to terminate with a message saying:

> Invalid input

Comment: You've omitted all the relevant code where you attempt to read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try/catch to catch the error and display a message of "invalid input" then terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    try{
        int i=Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());//place it in a loop if you want to read multiple lines
    }catch(Exception e){//it throws an exception if the line is not a number (e.g. if contains letters)
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.exit(2);
    }
```

Comment: A quick note: you should NOT use Scanner's nextInt() method for this. That method reads the next 4 bytes from the file, and return their value as an int. It doesnt care about the bytes being in a letter or in a number.